# Dudas sobre el try-catch en php

Tags: php

Buenas tardes y gracias de antemano por perder unos minutos de vuestro tiempo resolviendo mis dudas.
ahi va mi pregunta:¿Las excepciones en PHP se lanzan automaticamente como por ejemplo en java o se deben lanzar manualmente ?
Un saludo

Comment: Alberto, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Tu pregunta corre el riesgo de ser cerrada como demasiado amplia o como poco clara... Dinos al menos que leíste el [Manual de PHP sobre el tema](http://php.net/manual/es/language.exceptions.php) y si te quedó una duda entonces la podrás plantear más concretamente. El Manual tiene ejemplos de código para hacer pruebas y ver cómo funciona. La información está en castellano.

Answer (score 1):

PHP ya es capaz de lanzar errores mas comunes, por ejemplo una división por cero, o que no puede hacer una consulta, etc...

En caso de que quieras hacerlo tu, por ejemplo puedes comprobar (if) si los dos parámetros son números lo podaras hacer de la siguiente manera.

```
<?php 

    function comprobar($num1,$num2){

            if(is_numeric($num1) && is_numeric($num2)){
                echo "Son numeros";
            }else{
                throw new Exception("Error, los dos parametros tienen que ser numeros", 1);
            }

    }
    try {
        comprobar("asd",1);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        //Captamos la excepción si existe.
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

 ?>
```

Es decir las comprobaciones las tienes que hacer, y en caso necesario levantar una excepción.

También puedes añadir un bloque finally, que significa en cualquier caso haz esto. Ejemplo: Si tienes una conexión a una base de datos,  lo ideal seria cerrar la conexión al final de todo, utilizando el bloque finally.

Como ya dijo A.Cedano es mejor leer el manual de PHP, que esta muy bien explicado.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu respuesta, lo siento por no haber sido claro en mi explicación, es la primera vez que posteo.Si que habia leido la documentación y mas o menos lo habia entendido, pero una segunda opinion nunca viene mal..xD.